# Deleting method with nodejs Api from Sql DB

Tags: sql, node.js

I created a node.js api working with sql db , all get & Post methods works fine , but delete method is not working !!

I am using postman for testing my Api,

```
app.get('/getproduct/:id', function (req, res) {
        (async function GetProducts() {
            console.log("Request Received...");
            try {
                    result =  await sql.query`select * from Product where ID= ${req.params["id"]}`;
                    console.log(result);
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(result.recordsets[0][0]));
                    //res.sendStatus(200);
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
          })();
        });


app.delete('/delete/:id', function(req, res){

            (async function DeleteProduct() {
                console.log("Delete Request Received...");
                try{

                    await sql.query`DELETE FROM [Product] WHERE ID = ${req.params["id"]}`;
                    res.send({Status:"OK"});
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
              })();

          });
```

the get method works fine but delete method doesn't work ,why?
it doesn't even print the console.log output of delete function ?

Comment: `[Product]` -> `Product` ? also `sql.query` is a function right?  how come it accepts an argument without brackets?

Comment: @alfasin can you post your answer

Comment: @alfasin that is not the problem here it works fine without brackets , it is the syntax for mssql Package i use with my node app ,the problem is with the delete method only !

Comment: Print to log the string `DELETE FROM [Product] WHERE ID = ${req.params["id"]}` before you call `sql.query` and try to copy this output and run it directly against the DB, does it work there?

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now , just wrong placed function in my code , I implemented it inside another method , so i didn't work but now i fixed it and works fine , thanks for your support guys :)

Comment: I just have a question, why do you create a selfcalling function inside your routes (eg GetProducts), just interested nothing else.